# Error 3840 with self hosted parse server 2.2.9 and iOS sdk 1.13

Tags: parse-server

In my app delegate, I call

```
[Parse initializeWithConfiguration:[ParseClientConfiguration configurationWithBlock:^(id<ParseMutableClientConfiguration> configuration) {
    configuration.applicationId = @"MYAPPKEY";
    configuration.clientKey = @"";
    configuration.server = @"DOMAIN/parse";
}]];

// test parse
PFObject *gameScore = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"TestObject"];
gameScore[@"foo"] = @"bar";
[gameScore saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (succeeded) {
        // The object has been saved.
        NSLog(@"parse is working");
    } else {
        // There was a problem, check error.description
        NSLog(@"parse is not working: %@",error);
    }
}];
```

and I get the following error:

Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

I get the error from any call to parse.

My server works well with the Android SDK and the JS SDK, but I keep getting this error on iOS.  I've added my domain to the App Transport Security Settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can not leave the clientKey empty. The parse server does not use clientKey any more but it still crashes when its null.

```
configuration.clientKey = @"47b6r78tb3ynf907ynoe";
```

Comment: I just tried this but I'm still getting the error.  The documentation online says you can put @""...

Comment: @mogile_oli sorry I do not know what else could be causing it. Have you tried going to your server url and making sure that it says "I dream of being a website" or some thing like that.

Comment: Yep.  The server works fine.  I even connect to it fine with Android and javascript/web

Comment: @mogile_oli You could have changed some thing on the server that could be causing this error and not the configuration. Because when I query objects my server works just fine with that configuration.

Comment: I recreated the server from scratch and I have it working now.

Answer (score 0):

You should try with adding a / after the

`configuration.server = @"DOMAIN/parse";`

so it looks like

`configuration.server = @"DOMAIN/parse/";`